# How to configure YoastSEO for redirecting duplicate subdirectory paths in WordPress Multisite

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect, multisite, yoast

I'm working with a WordPress Multisite setup where one of the subsites is located in a subdirectory named /en/. I've encountered an issue where URLs that include a duplicate subdirectory path, specifically /en/en/, need to be redirected to just /en/.

For example, I want https://example.com/en/en/some-page/ to redirect to https://example.com/en/some-page/.

I attempted to set up this redirection using YoastSEO, which allows for RegEx-based redirects. However, my current setup does not seem to work as expected. Here's what I've tried:

- RegEx pattern: ^en/en/(.+)
- Destination URL: /en/$1

Despite this setup, the redirection fails and URLs with the duplicate /en/en/ path are not redirected properly.

Is there anything wrong with my RegEx pattern?

Comment: try matching `(en\/){2,}` and replacing with `$1`. See https://regex101.com/r/VJsqG4/latest. I think your issue is, that `^` anchors your expression to the start of string, while `en/` is in fact in the middle of the URL